# ChildViewController with UITableView, cell constraint error

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitextview, uistoryboard

I used storyboard to build a ViewController that will used as a ChildViewController. Inside this view controller is a UITableView with a single UITextView.

The UITextView has only 4 constraints (Leading, Trailing, Top, and Bottom space to container) to it's super view, which is the TableViewCell's content view (see below)

[image: UITextView and it's constraints]

However, the trailing constraint is not working properly when running in the simulator. The UITextView goes beyond the UITableViewCell (see below)

[image: Simulator Rendering]

Both the leading and trailing constraints are set to a constant of 16, so there should be a blue border on the right side of the UITextView, but the UITextView extends past the cell...

I've never had this issue with a UITableView in a UIViewController, but I am today when I am using the ViewController as a child view controller. Could this possibly be an issue? Am I missing something?

Comment: it seems it's 16 from image but recheck it's not -16 , also when you add the view of the child to the parent Vc , call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() for both the child and parent views , followed by childVC.tabel.reloadData() ,,, in cellForRow call **cell.layoutIfNeeded()** before **return cell**

Comment: It's not -16. And I attempted the cell.layoutIfNeeded(). I am also using sizeToFit() on the UITextView, and I'm wondering if that is an issue?

Comment: I fixed my issue with it by replacing the UITextView with a UILabel, but it's still weird that it's not correct with a UITextView...

Comment: you use fixed or automatic cell ?

Comment: I am using automatic